# Efetuar login em um sistema via cURL e exibir os dados de outra página

Tags: php, libcurl

Estou tentando exibir o conteúdo de uma página após efetuar o login no sistema.

O login é efetuado com sucesso, recebo o bem-vindo do sistema, porém ao alterar a URL e fazer um novo `curl_exec` recebo `http_code = 302`, mas acessando via navegador a página existe normalmente.

```
$username = $_GET['username'];
$password = $_GET['password'];
$data = array('josso_cmd' => 'login', 'josso_username' => $username, 'josso_password' => $password);

$url = "...";
$referer = "...";
$user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.118 Safari/537.36";
$url_notas = "...";
$referer_notas = "...";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $referer);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, dirname(__FILE__) . '/cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, dirname(__FILE__). '/cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);

print_r(curl_exec($ch));
print_r(curl_errno($ch));
print_r(curl_getinfo($ch));

echo "<hr>";

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url_notas);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $referer_notas);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0);

print_r(curl_exec($ch));
print_r(curl_errno($ch));
print_r(curl_getinfo($ch));
```

O retorno é:

> HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily

Ele me retorna a URL de login, como se tivesse perdido seção.

Minha dúvida é **onde estou errando?**

Comment: Tentou alterar `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);`para `true`?

Comment: Já sim @RafaelWithoeft, não surte diferença alguma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problema resolvido.

Realmente era o `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION`, porei no servidor que estava testando o php estava em **safe_mode** e não realizava o redirecionamento.

Setei o `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION = true` e rodei em outro servidor, neste obtive sucesso e o retorno da página esperada.